# django reverse error NoReverseMatch

Tags: django, reverse

given the following

views.py

```
return redirect('order-review', order=order.id)
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^review/$', 'checkout.views.review', {'order': '0'},  name="order-review"),
```

aimed at

views.py

```
def review(request, order):
```

is there a really obvious fix? I just can't see what i've got wrong and the django docco is slightly light on examples when passing a variable through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't resolve, because your url pattern actually hard-codes the *order* value (it will always be '0').

You have to provide a way to change the *order* value from within the URL itself.

To be precise:

urls.py

```
url(r'^review/$', 'checkout.views.review', {'order':'0'},  name="order-review-default-fallback"),
url(r'^review/(?P<order>[\d]+)/$', 'checkout.views.review', {},  name="order-review"),
```

should solve your problem.

Comment: thanks, this was just what i needed. thought that by supplying a default i was telling it what to amend but now i understand why thats not the case.

Comment: Actually, if you set a default value of the view function keyword argument ('def review(request, order=0)'), it will work as you wished.