# DJANGO PYTHON : NoReverseMatch at : Reverse for 'views.login' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Tags: django, reverse

I need some help on django 1.8

**ERROR :** 
*Exception Type : NoReverseMatch* 
*Exception Value : Reverse for 'views.login' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []*

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [  
    url(r"^login/$", TemplateView.as_view(template_name = 'auth/login.html'))
]
```

login.html

```
<html>
   <body>
      <!-- action = "{% url 'connecte_login' %}" -->
      <form name = "form" action = "{% url 'views.login' %}" method = "POST" >
           {% csrf_token %}
         <div style = "max-width:470px;">
            <center>
              <h5> <font color="blue">KEYSTONE AUTHENTIFICATION </font> </h5>

              <b>Username :</b>  <input type = "text" style = "margin-left:7%;"
                  placeholder = "Identifiant" name = "username" />
            </center>
         </div>

      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from .forms import *

 def login(request):
   return render(request, "auth/authSuccess.html", context_dic)
```

authSuccess.html

```
<html>
   <body> <b>IT WORKS !</b> </body>
</html>
```

I don't know why it gives me that error !

thank you.

Comment: There are at least 10 duplicate questions on the right in the related section. Please attempt to solve the problem yourself first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django reverse error NoReverseMatch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378323/django-reverse-error-noreversematch)

Comment: I saw them, but it didn't help me :(

Comment: Please update your question to include what you've tried and researched then. You need to give your url a name and then use that name.

Comment: @Sayse, why i'm going to give it a name? I use that url only to get to my login template !!

Comment: the problem is here : {% url 'views.login' %} in login.html

Comment: Because thats what the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#url) told you to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Sayse says in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38351989/django-python-noreversematch-at-reverse-for-views-login-with-arguments#comment64116833_38351989), documentation told you to give your view a name to use reverse lookup. To understand how it works you need to look at `django.core.urlresolvers.RegexURLResolver#_reverse_with_prefix` method. Here in line 462 (Django 1.9) it executes `possibilities = self.reverse_dict.getlist(lookup_view)`, where lookup_view is your `'views.login'` argument of url template tag. So you don't have this name - it wont work.

Hovever, you *can* use full dotted path to your view like this:

`{% url 'path.to.some_view' v1 v2 %}`

Not `views.view` but `app.views.view`. But you should *not* do this since it is deprecated and will removed in Django 1.10. Hope it will help you.